# Kotlin: list or sequence to find nested item

Tags: list, kotlin, sequence, nested-lists

I have a list, each element of which contains an inner list.
I need to get an element of the outer list, in which the specified condition is fulfilled for the inner list at least once.
I wrote code like this:

```
 outerList?.find {
        !it.items.isNullOrEmpty() && it.items?.any { item ->
            item.isVisible == visibility &&
                item.progress == currentProgress
        } == true
    }?.let { outerItem ->
        currentItem = outerItem
        // here some logic      
    } ?: run {
        currentItem = null
        // here some logic      
    }
```

But I'm not sure if this code is efficient. Perhaps you should use sequences instead of a list?
Can you please tell me which solution will be the most efficient in terms of execution time and memory consumption for my case?

Comment: For me It is ok, I can't make up how to improve it. **Sequence** doesn't help there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence isn't going to help here, because you are only performing one operation on the outer list, and one operation on the inner list.

Your `!it.items.isNullOrEmpty()` check is entirely redundant to the `?.any` you follow it up with, so you can remove that. Perhaps the cleanest way to write this would be:

```
outerList?.find {
    it.items.orEmpty().any { item ->
        item.isVisible == visibility && item.progress == currentProgress
    }
}
```

Never do this: `?.let { ... } ?: run { }`. Aside from being very poor for readability, it is error-prone. If you accidentally return null from the `let` block, the `run` block will also be run unexpectedly.